# Spring OutputStream - download pptx with IE

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stream, java-8

I use this Java code to download files from a web application:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/filedownloads/filedownload/{userid}/{projectid}/{documentfileid}/{version}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public void filesDownload(final @PathVariable("userid") String userId, final @PathVariable("projectid") String projectId,
        final @PathVariable("documentfileid") String documentFileId, final @PathVariable("version") String version,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, BusinessException {

    ...

    final String fileName = "filename=" + documentFile.getFileName();
    final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; " + fileName);
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

if I will download a pptx- file I get the following IE- page:

[image: opend pptx in IE]

What I want to do is to open the downloaded file in Powerpoint.
My question now would be if there is a header setting in order to open this file with the right application (in this case Powerpoint)

Answer (score 3):

Simply try to set the `Content Type` header properly which is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` in case a `pptx`, as next:

```
response.setContentType(
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"
);
response.setHeader(
    "Content-Disposition", 
    String.format("inline; filename=\"%s\"", documentFile.getFileName())
);
response.setContentLength((int) new File(filePath).length());
```

[Here is the list of mime types corresponding to Office 2007 documents.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little sample code from a Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/ppt")
public void downloadPpt(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("Presentation1.pptx");

    InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Presentation1.pptx\"");
    response.setContentLengthLong(resource.contentLength());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = resourceInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

}
```

By setting the  `Content-Disposition` to `attachment`, you're telling the browser to download this file as an attachment and by supplying the correct file name with extension, you're telling the Operating System to use whatever application the user normally uses to open a file of this type. In this case it will be MS Power Point.

This way you can get away with not knowing exactly what version of Power Point the file was created with.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested code in `IE-11` its work fine. See below code i.e

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadfile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void downloadfile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = null;

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=downloadppt.pptx");

            byte[] ppt = downloadFile();

            servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            servletOutputStream.write(ppt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            servletOutputStream.flush();
            servletOutputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Generate `bytes` from saved `pptx` file.

```
public byte[] downloadFile() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("e:/testppt.pptx"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =  new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Transfer bytes from source to destination
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

That's it, you are able to download `pptx` file. Hope code help you, if you have any query or doubt then we can discuss or if any suggestions. Thank you